# Jquery Appending Html Instead of Layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

My Concern is, I am fetching raw HTML from the database as a string using ajax. all set.

But whenever I am appending it into a DIV, it is placing whole the code as it is and not converting it into a layout format.

The code is as below:

**JQuery**

```
var str='&lt;textarea rows="4" cols="10" class="form-control physical_examination(urine)_field1" name="physical_examination(urine)_field1[]" placeholder=""&gt;&lt;/textarea><br/>&lt;textarea rows="4" cols="10" class="form-control physical_examination(urine)_field2" name="physical_examination(urine)_field2[]" placeholder=""&gt;&lt;/textarea><br/>&lt;textarea rows="4" cols="10" class="form-control physical_examination(urine)_field3" name="physical_examination(urine)_field3[]" placeholder=""&gt;&lt;/textarea><br/>&lt;textarea rows="4" cols="10" class="form-control physical_examination(urine)_field4" name="physical_examination(urine)_field4[]" placeholder=""&gt;&lt;/textarea><br/>&lt;textarea rows="4" cols="10" class="form-control physical_examination(urine)_field5" name="physical_examination(urine)_field5[]" placeholder=""&gt;&lt;/textarea><br/>';

var generatedView=$(".generatedView");

generatedView.append(str);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="generatedView"></div>
```

**Output**

textarea_html_view_presented:

[image]

**Output Expected**

textarea_html_DOM_view_expected:

[image]

Comment: &lt; to < and &gt; to >

Comment: you can parse html with jquery

Comment: If it contains `&lt;` and `&gt;`, then it isn’t actually “raw HTML” … and the question would be, why it isn’t. It seems to make rather little sense, that you send an “encoded” version from the server, only to have to “decode” it again on the client. So why is this not sending _proper_ “raw” HTML to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the entities and then parse the HTML qith jQuery

```javascript
const input  = '.... see question ....',
      html   = input
          .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
          .replace(/&gt;/g, '>'),
      parsed = $.parseHTML(html);

$(".generatedView").append(parsed);
```

**NOTE:** this is a simplistic approach. If you have other entities in your input you should look into a real entity decode module.

Comment: it is only replacing the first occurrence of either &lt; or &gt;

Comment: Sorry, developer asleep at the keyboard :-) Fixed.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer to close the question, if you are satisfied with it.